# How can I do POST query knowing its headers and its POLL respond?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-post

I am trying to understand what happens when I click a button, I get a POST request to which I get POLL request (the result). Now I want to be able to do the request without clicking, without using event triggers, I want to be able to do the request by typing it to the Firebug -command line. The button has a keydown -event with function `"fn.apply(object, args)"` which calls some object and args which I don't know yet.

1. Without the information, is there some way to redo the just done POST request without clicking?

Related post here where I am asking about [events](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6137726/164148), now the scope is just trying to replicate POST -request to get POLL request.

I think I have all relevant information stored to the browser with things such as session ID so I need just to trigger the function which triggers the POST query or to trigger the POST query directly.

2. How can I do the POST query?
3. If I cannot do the POST query again with these information, what else do I need to do a POST query?
4. What does the Silverlight usage with SVC infer? Do I need to format the query somehow or is the POST query standardized?

**POST/POLL URLS**

```
http://game.com/Presentation/Service.svc/ajaxEndpoint/StartSearch
http://game.com/Presentation/Service.svc/ajaxEndpointPoll
```

**POST StartSearch**

```
Request Headers
Host    game.com
User-Agent      Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.17) Gecko/20110422 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.17
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive      115
Connection      keep-alive
Content-Type    application/json; charset=UTF-8
X-Qooxdoo-Response-Type application/json
Referer http://game.com/index.aspx
Content-Length  110
Cookie  __utma=30514082.25780803.1305937283.1306259330.1306374895.6; __utmz=30514082.1306376876.6.8.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=JSON%20site%3Agame.com; __utmb=30514082.9.10.1306374895; __utmv=; __utmc=30514082; s_sq=%5B%5BB%5D%5D; s_cc=true; s_ria=flash%2010%7Csilverlight%20not%20detected
Pragma  no-cache
Cache-Control   no-cache
```

**POLL Request Headers**

```
POST /Presentation/Service.svc/ajaxEndpoint/Poll HTTP/1.1
Host: game.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.17) Gecko/20110422 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.17
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
X-Qooxdoo-Response-Type: application/json
Referer: http://game.com/index.aspx
Content-Length: 295
Cookie: __utma=30514082.25780803.1305937283.1306259330.1306374895.6; __utmz=30514082.1306376876.6.8.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=JSON%20site%3Agame.com; __utmv=; __utmc=30514082; s_sq=%5B%5BB%5D%5D; s_cc=true; s_ria=flash%2010%7Csilverlight%20not%20detected
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

**[Update]**

Directed by reply to Ajax, I think it may work something like below. It runs but do not work as supposed (debugging...):

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();

client.open("POST", "http://game.com/Presentation/Service.svc/ajaxEndpoint/StartSearch", true);
client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
client.send('{"session":"xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx","cityid":"787878788","maxGold":0,"resType":0,"maxTime":86400}');

alert( client.getResponseText );
// document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML= client.responseText;
```

**Format of the JSON in POLL reply from POST request**

One format of the JSON, apparently having some sort of validating stuff before request. It is received after the POST query as a POLL. If I can understand right, I need a new request ID, new time and I may need to update something.

```
{"session":"xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx","requestid":"111","requests":"UA:\fMM:888,0,\fCAT:1\fSERVER:\fALLIANCE:\fQUEST:\fEE:\fPLAYER:\fCITY:111111111\fWC:\fWORLD:\fVIS:c:111111111:0:-1111:-111:222:444\fUFP:\fREPORT:\fMAIL:\fFRIENDINV:\fTIME:11111111111111\fCHAT:\fSUBSTITUTION:\fINV:\fALL_AT:\fMAT:333333333\fSEARCH:\f"}
```

**jQuery option**

many answers suggest jQuery so I ran the jQuery source [here](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.js) in Firebug but not getting it working, trying. It is probably the easiest way to do the POST query. If someone could tell some sort of vizualiser to see my POLL queries, it would be greatly appreciated (not knowing certain which is wrong, using firebug's profiler and debugger). It may be that I do not catch the output but it is coming, currently receiving `undefined` as reply.

Answer (score 1):

WOW you looked to much into what you computer is doing and what you need to do,

Go look up AJAX (XMLHttpRequest) -- http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

For best result use jQuery

$().ajax(
  url:""
  data:{"pollPostName":"pollactiveID"}
  dataType:"json"
);

If you give me the full link for how i can access the poll i will write it for you. using what every frameworks you have or dont have if native is needed

Comment: sorry I do not understand the example, [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first), when I copy paste that code to file and then `$ echo "hello world!" > ajax_info.txt`, it does not work like on the site. In order to use the Ajax, do I need to do some configurations? It would be cool to try Ajax on my own machine.

Comment: It is very hard for me to understand how the POST really work. I could see that the connection works like server pinging in certain time-periods (just to keep alive) but I am confused how things work forward. There are a number of POST/POLL things I have investigated, trying to learn from them, one is the game [here](http://www.lordofultima.com/en/game/index) (JS game so I can see code and learn from that cool but code obfuscated, lacking descriptive names etc). Is your jQuery suggestion valid for arbitrary game, can it be used every time in userspace with POST/Poll?

Comment: [It'd probably be better to find a different source than w3schools](http://w3fools.com/).

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213723/how-can-i-do-a-ajax-post-javascript-thing-to-get-trading-data-with-one-click-in

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

write a function that triggers $.post
then you can use that function in the JS command line.

Comment: do you need to import the whole jQuery -pkg to get this working?